# How to project gradient vector to subspace defined by linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following set of linear constraints:

$$\begin {align}\textbf{y}^T\textbf {x} &= 0 \\ \textbf {0} &\leq\textbf {x} \leq C\cdot\textbf {1},\end {align}$$

where $\textbf {y} \in \{-1, 1\}^n, \textbf {x} \in \mathbb {R}^n, \; C \in \mathbb {R}$. I want project the gradient of a quadratic function $f (\textbf {x}) $ into the subspace defined by these constraints where movement  along this projected gradient does not violate the constraints.

How can I get this projected gradient vector?

P.S. [here](https://grapr.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/luenberger-linear-and-nonlinear-programming-3e-springer-2008.pdf) is my reference I've been using. Scroll to page 367, 12.4 The Gradient Projection Method. The gradient projection method assumes that you start at a feasible point $\textbf{x}_0$. Then you create the matrix $A_q$ which consists of the rows of the active constraints, that this constraints where $\textbf{a}_i^T\textbf{x}_0=b_i$. In my case the active constraints for the initial solution $\textbf{x}_0=\textbf{0}$ (which is feasible) are:

$$\textbf{y}^T\textbf{x}_0=0$$

and

$$\textbf{x}_0\geq\textbf{0}$$

so my matrix $A_q$ is a $(n+1)\times n$ matrix:

$$A_q=\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & \dots  & y_n \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

at feasible solution $\textbf{x}_0=\textbf{0}$. Now in my [reference](https://grapr.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/luenberger-linear-and-nonlinear-programming-3e-springer-2008.pdf) (page 367, last two lines) it is stated:

> To compute this projection let $A_q$ be defined as composed of the
>   rows of working constraints. Assuming regularity of the constraints,
>   as we shall always assume, $A_q$ will be a $q\times n$ matrix of rank
>   $q < n$.

Well, my matrix $A_q$ is of rank $q=n \not< n$. How to proceed?

Comment: Are you asking how to take a proper projected gradient step here, or are you asking how to project the gradient? Those are two different things. A projected gradient algorithm projects $x-tg$ into the constraint set, where $x$ is the last iterate and $g$ is the gradient---not $g$ alone.

Comment: Hi @MichaelGrant if you want to provide me both the projected gradient and the optimal step, that would perfect :) I'm trying to code this myself so I need the details :) thank you! Whatever you can tell me that will help me to actually code this myself is more than welcome ;)

Comment: I hope that cleared your question :) please let me know if you need more clarification :)

Comment: My final goal is to use gradient projection method to minimize this quadratic function $f$ subject to the constraints shown

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this for a class you're taking?  If your goal is just to solve your optimization problem, better methods might be available.

Comment: Hi @littleO no, this is for my own curiosity :) I'm studying about the learning method Support Vector Machines (SVM) and while I've been studying it I have noticed that there are no good examples on the web or sources on how to actually implement it from beginning to the end. I hate it when I read the materials they always say: "this is what SVM is AND for solving the parameters we use A PACKAGE" so it's like a black box what I'm using :( and I really want to know what's happening under the hood. Like if I'm a new student and I want to understand how SVM works I want to understand what SVM is.

Comment: ..and HOW it is implemented. Basically I want to make a tutorial for a beginner student about SVM on 1) What SVM is and 2) How to implement and optimize it. I want to include everything from explanation to actual implementation without the usage of any packages. So that the reader himself can code SVM from beginning to end.

Comment: Ah I see.  There is a class of optimization algorithms called "proximal algorithms" that can be used to solve problems like training support vector machines.  They are neat algorithms that tend to be easy to implement.  I recommend checking out the Boyd and Parikh [book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prox_algs.html) and also Vandenberghe's [236c notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html) to learn about proximal algorithms.

Comment: Another good reference is Boyd's [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/admm_distr_stats.html) "Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers", which mentions Support Vector Machines.

Comment: Thank you =) appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but here is a different algorithm you could possibly use to solve the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad \frac12 x^T A x + b^T x \\
\text{subect to} & \quad y^T x = 0 \\
& \quad 0 \leq x \leq c
\end{align}
where the matrix $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite.

Let $U = \{x \mid y^T x = 0\}$ and let $V = \{x \mid 0 \leq x \leq c \}$.
Also let $I_U$ be the indicator function of $U$, defined by:
\begin{equation}
I_U(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad \text{if } x \in U \\ \infty &\quad \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} \end{equation}
The indicator function of $V$, denoted $I_V$, is defined similarly.

The optimization problem can be reformulated as
\begin{equation}
\text{minimize} \quad \underbrace{\frac12 x^T Ax + b^T x + I_U(x)}_{g(x)} + \underbrace{I_V(x)}_{h(x)}.
\end{equation}
There is a very popular optimization algorithm called the Douglas-Rachford method that will allow you to minimize a sum of two simple functions like this.
You could implement the Douglas-Rachford method for this problem in a page of Matlab.

At each iteration of the Douglas-Rachford method, you will have to evaluate the "proximal operators" of $g$ and $h$.  The proximal operator of $g$ (with parameter $t > 0$) is defined by
\begin{equation}
\text{prox}_{tg}(\hat x) = \arg \min_x g(x) + \frac{1}{2t} \|x - \hat x\|_2^2,
\end{equation}
and the proximal operator of $h$ is defined similarly.  You can work out simple closed form expressions for the proximal operators of $g$ and $h$.
To evaluate the proximal operator of $h$, you can see that we need only project onto $V$.  And to evaluate the proximal operator of $g$, we must minimize a quadratic function subject to linear constraints.

One issue with this method is that evaluating the proximal operator of $g$ will require solving a linear system of equations involving $A$, which might be difficult if your problem is very large scale.  If $A$ is sparse or has some other structure we can exploit then that might help a lot.

The Douglas-Rachford iteration is:
\begin{align*}
x^k &= \text{prox}_{tg}( z^{k-1}) \\
y^k &= \text{prox}_{th}(2 x^k - z^{k-1}) \\
z^k &= z^{k-1} + y^k - x^k.
\end{align*}
You pick the parameter $t > 0$ and also the initial values
$x^0,y^0,z^0$ however you like.

Comment: Thank you very much! =) I will look into the literature you provided and the solution you presented here :) Appreciate it!