# Simplex optimization: how to project to nearest feasible point, with box constraints and total constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am working in a simplex-based constrained optimization setting, wherein several texts suggest that algorithms such as Nelder-Mead can be modified for constraints by projecting an infeasible point onto the nearest feasible point, but are sparse in terms of details on how to do so. I am trying to determine how to project points in such a manner in my own setting.

Suppose our feasible region is in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For point $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, we have an overall constraint of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n x_n = k$ for constant $k$, as well as box constraints of the form $l_i \le x_i \le u_i$, for $i=1,...,n$ and constants $l_1,...,l_n$ and $u_1,...,u_n$. For an infeasible point $x$, I am interested in obtaining the point $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ that minimizes the Euclidian distance to $x$ and satisfies the box constraints and overall constraint above.

Could anyone please advise me on how to do this, and/or refer me to relevant books or resources that have additional detail? I found a somewhat similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274457/how-to-project-gradient-vector-to-subspace-defined-by-linear-constraints/1276934#1276934) but the answer was specialized in a manner that does not directly apply to my problem. (Note that I will eventually consider constraints of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n c_n x_n = k$ for constants $c_1,...,c_n$.)

Comment: It indeed has a closed-form solution, but why not turn to an iterative algorithm which would end within finite steps? See Douglas-Rachford splitting method which is very useful to handle such a problem.

Comment: @foxell Could you list a reference for the closed-form solution?

Comment: I am sorry. I have underestimated the complexity of this problem. It does not admit a closed-form solution. See the paper  [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.6081)

Comment: The referenced paper seems to address projection onto a simplex, but to clarify, I'm only asking about how to project a single point of the simplex. I mentioned the use of a simplex to clarify the context, although it has no direct bearing on the underlying mathematical structure of the problem.  The problem seems like it may have a straightforward solution for someone with expertise in linear algebra.